# Symfony 3 upload by FTP

Tags: php, symfony, ftp, php-7

Hello I am trying to upload a symfony 3 project to the hosting.

The hosting php version is 7.

I am uploading It by FTP beacause I do not have SSH acces and I request to the support of the hosting, and I do not have the right acount for have SSH user.

On localhost with xamp the proyect run perfectly but when I uploaded It, the next issue apears:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught RuntimeException: Session Storage was not able to create directory "\app/../var/sessions/prod" in var/cache/prod/classes.php:292 Stack trace: #0 /var/cache/prod/appProdProjectContainer.php(2131): Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\Handler\NativeFileSessionHandler->__construct('/usr/home/farma...') #1 /vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php(274): appProdProjectContainer->getSession_HandlerService() #2 /var/cache/prod/appProdProjectContainer.php(2170): Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get('session.handler') #3 /vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php(274): appProdProjectContainer->getSession_Storage_Native in /vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Loader/Filesystem.php on line 94
```

I read some problems like these on stack and I tryied change the permission of the forlders making them at 777 however It not work.

Someone know how can I solve these? Or other idea for try?

PD: 
Right now looking the [structure folder](http://prntscr.com/d2hawo) I saw a strange folder.
That folder is "var\logs". I can not delete It also It creates after I try inside symfony project. 
On local I do not have that fodler.

Answer (score 1):

Try to clear cache by this command:

```
bin/console cache:clear --env=prod
```

Or delete var/cache/ manualy

Comment: I can not access console, also is a clean project with out cache. Is just the symfony installation

Comment: try to delete cache, log and give var 777 just for testing.

Comment: I was cleaning other var/chache It create. Thanks.